# Why my server and remote ip showing same?

Tags: php, ip

I just noticed that all my user have same ip. it was working fine till yesterday.

i was using code below to get user ip and its returning server ip `65.254.32.34`:

```
<?php
function getrealip() {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}       
?>
```

I am now doing test with this `code` and its showing same both the ip.

```
<?php
echo 'Server IP: ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] . '<br />';
echo 'Your IP: ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
{
   echo '<br />Forwarded For: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
?>
```

Output is:

```
Server IP: 65.254.32.34
Your IP: 65.254.32.34
```

where as my ip is : 115.240.13.83

i made one page with my second code : http://ffsplus2.com/myip.php

Comment: @tlenss are you sure its giving you your ip? not server ip?

Comment: The code works fine. Your code outputs the same address. Is your server sitting behind a proxy?

Comment: its not only me but all my 3k user have same ip.. i get there ip with my first code above.

Comment: It's not a PHP issue. It seems to be a server configuration issue

Comment: Thanks @tlenss i will have to check things on server configuration

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your nginx server is not set up properly.
Check out [this](http://chrismorris.org/passing-ip-from-nginx-to-apache/) article.

Answer (score 1):

if your server is behind a proxy on the same machine and the proxy do not set remote_addr to client ip, it may happens. The remote_addr record the ip who send the request to this server.

```
Client -> Proxy -> Server
```

Like the model above, for Proxy, the remote ip addr is Client ip, for Server, the remote ip addr is Proxy ip if proxy do not set correctly.